# Subdomain or URL: customer.acmecompany.com or acmecompany.com/customer

Tags: url, dns, subdomain

What's *reasons* should be for moving functionality into subdomain, example,

cusomer portal  - **customers.acmecompany.com**

forum - **forum.acmecompany.com**

Instead of making it

**acmecompany.com/Customers**

**acmecompany.com/help**

Answer (score 2):

One good reason for using sub-domains would be if apps are hosted on different computers. Then you can let DNS do the appropriate routing for you whereas with the acmecompany.com/$APPNAME version you would have to set up a front end proxy. If all of your apps are hosted on the same machine (and will be for the foreseeable future) this is a non-issue.

From a user-experience standpoint I would also argue that if the apps look significantly different or require different logins then they should be in subdomains. If I click a link and end up on a page that LOOKS like a different app or requires a new login then I expect it to be at a different FQDN. But this point is very subjective.

Other than that I think it's just whatever is easier for you to set up.